# Jmeter delay thread creation until needed and constant timer

Tags: timer, jmeter

Suppose inside a thread group with delay thread creation until needed option selected,if we add a constant timer of 30 seconds before a http request,then the thread should get created after 30 seconds right?
That is the number of active threads should be zero for 30 seconds.But i am not getting that.When I start running the threadgroup,the number of active threads started increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Timer comes into place while sending the samplers. Not for thread creation. If you want to delay thread creation by 30 seconds, you should have enough ramp-up period.

If you have 10 users, give the ramp-up period as 300 seconds. You would see a thread being created for every 30 seconds. (assuming delay thread creation until needed option selected)

Comment: But a thread is needed when i send a http request rite...so if i send a timer before the request,why the thread is being created..?  my need is like,there are 100 users.Initially all these users will send a request to a server. And the server responds with a wait time.So after getting the response the user will wait for the prescribed wait time and send the request again to some other server.The problem here is,When the adding a wait time using the constant timer,the thread is still active which leads to memory utilization.

Comment: So to optimize the utilization,I m planning to kill the thread after receiving the wait time from the first response.and restart the thread after the wait time,so that number of active threads will be less in the system

Answer (score 0):

To add a little more detail to Vinoth's answer:

JMeter allocates all threads at the test start unless the Thread Group option "Delay Thread creation until needed" is selected.

In some cases where a test has a very large number of threads the CPU can spike to 100% and kill the server process if the delay thread creation option is not selected.

When selected, JMeter will allocate threads according to the ramp up times.  Otherwise all threads are allocated to the JVM process the moment the test is started, regardless of ramp up time.

This has no relation to whether or not the threads are allowed to begin sending samples.  That always depends on ramp-up time and and test plan timers.

-Addled

Comment: Actually my need is to give different wait times before starting a thread.That is if i have 10 requests,each request have to wait for different time periods ,before the request is send. so can i give different ramp up period for each threads? or rampup period is for the thread group?